# How do you use an npm library on the front-end with webpack ?

Tags: node.js, webpack

A couple projects I've seen seem to be usable on the *front-end*, but the only "Install" instruction in the doc is a `npm install xxx` line.

The projects use webpack, and it's either obvious, or requiring a plugin that I'm missing, but I could not find anything related to npm modules in the [webpack docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs)

My google / reading skills being obviously failing, could someone please RTFM me about the steps on how to go from :

```
npm install foo
```

to running this in a *browser* :

```
var foo = require("foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, turns out that's because you... hardly have anything to do.

In my case :

```
npm install -g webpack
npm install babel-loader
npm install redux
```

In webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./public/javascripts/entry.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "./public/javascripts/bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.jsx?$/,
              exclude: /(node_modules|vendor)/,
              loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

In entry.js :

```
var redux = require("redux");
console.log(redux)
```

And things work... will flag for closing.